# Rooting android device

Tags: android

I need to root my android phone.  I have read many guides on how to do this, but they all are outdated.

I have been reading the guide at http://www.pocketables.com/2011/06/how-to-manually-root-almost-any-android-device.html to root it, but when I get to the `./psneuter` step, I get a message saying that mmap() failed because of an argument error.

I have read that this is outdated.  Is this true?  And if it is, what can I do to root my device?

I am running android 4.4.2 on a Samsung Galaxy S 4, and my computer is Windows 8.

Comment: _Which_ device do you have, and what version of Android is it running? Most of these guides do indeed become outdated after a few months, as they usually rely on security holes that get fixed later (and sometimes are present only in specific models). See [this Android.SE post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device).

Comment: I updated my post with this info.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Since this question was closed for being off-topic: perhaps [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to root your phone is to find a custom rom that you can upload using odin.

Reboot your phone and hold `volume up`+`home`+`power` to go into odin download mode. Then from the pc, you can upload the custom rom to your phone.

Also, you never *need* to root your phone, but I guess you *want* to root your phone. Big difference.